# How to prevent expansion of : in hyperlink?

Tags: bibliographies, cross-referencing

I'm trying to make a simple environment to enter a (personal) review of a paper and cross-reference to it, using the following commands:

```
\newenvironment{articlereview}[2][]{%
  \hypertarget{review:#2}{\textcolor{blue}{\texttt{#2:}}}\cite{#2} (#1)
}{
  \medskip
}
\newcommand\linktoreview[1]{\hyperlink{review:#1}{\nolinkurl{#1}}}
```

I then use them this way:

```
\begin{articlereview}[date]{nice:paper}
My review...
\end{articlereview}

See review of paper \linktoreview{nice:paper}
```

The issue is that for some reason, I can't get rid of the `:` special char expansion in `\linktoreview`, and I get errors of the like:

```
 name{review:nice\\unskip\040\\penalty\040\\@M\040\040:paper}  has been referenced but does not exist, replaced by a fixed one
```

What I am doing wrong ?

**Edit**
Here is a minimal (non) working example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\bibliographystyle{unsrt}

\newenvironment{articlereview}[2][]{%
  \hypertarget{review:#2}{\texttt{#2:}}\cite{#2} (#1)
}{
  \medskip
}
\newcommand\linktoreview[1]{\hyperlink{review:#1}{\nolinkurl{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{articlereview}[date]{nice:paper}
My review...
\end{articlereview}

See review of paper \linktoreview{nice:paper}

\bibliography{Biblio}

\end{document}
```

As mentioned by David Carlisle, if I comment out the `babel` line, then all goes fine. The problem is the following: the `nice:paper` is a reference (well, many) in a `.bib` file, I'm not going to change those. Wrapping manually each use of `:` is also not possible (there's hundreds of them !), and it feels like "it should be possible to make it work" (since it works with other labels.

Comment: You haven't shown relevant code but I would guess you are using a French typesetting option where `:` is an active character that adjusts the white space

Comment: A basic example with this code in works for me, except that I think you want `\label` instead of `\cite` in the definition of `articlereview`. Thus, as @DavidCarlisle says, there is something else going on.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle you are correct, I am using French typesetting. The problem is I can't just disable the `:` expansion everywhere, since it's useful, and not around every instance of `\linktoreview{nice:paper}`. I will provide a MWE later on.

Comment: you could use `\string:` or just use a different letter, `-` or `_` or anything not made active by babel.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I've added an example. I hope my requirements are now more clear. Thanks for your help.

Comment: With a recent version of babel it should work (at least, works for me). See https://github.com/latex3/babel/wiki/What's-new-in-babel-3.35 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can detokenize the label/anchor argument:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\bibliographystyle{unsrt}

\newenvironment{articlereview}[2][]{%
  \expandafter\hypertarget\expandafter{\detokenize{review:#2}}{\texttt{#2:}}\cite{#2} (#1)
}{
  \medskip
}
\newcommand\linktoreview[1]{\expandafter\hyperlink\expandafter{\detokenize{review:#1}}{\nolinkurl{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{articlereview}[date]{nice:paper}
My review...
\end{articlereview}



See review of paper \linktoreview{nice:paper}

\bibliography{Biblio}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect ! This is exactly what I was looking for !